# XUnit 'Startup' does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit, asp.net-core-2.1

In my xunit project i am getting bellow error

> The type or namespace name 'Startup' does not exist in the namespace 'TestService' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [Testervice.Tests]

I added the TestService reference to the Testervice.Tests by using

```
dotnet add reference ..\TestService\TestService.csproj
```

The reference was added successfully the the test project and its also available in TestService.csproj file. But still i am getting the error. Why i am getting the error.Any one try help me.

Comment: Can you show which line throws this error?

Comment: Have you defined `Startup.cs` in your `TestService.csproj`? What is the project type for `TestService.csproj`? Share us file structor for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this will solve your problem but what you need to is create a TestStartUp class which inherits the original Startup.cs to properly build your .net core app. Sample code is shown below.

```
    public class TestStartup : Startup
    {
        public TestStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) : base(configuration, hostingEnvironment)
        {

        }
    }
```

Hope this solves your problem.